# Chrome e bug background fixed

Tags: javascript, html, css, front-end, google-chrome

Estou com o seguinte problema:

Possuo algumas seções na página separadas em divs. Duas dessas divs recebem uma imagem como `background` e `background-position:fixed`, então quando rola a página as imagens devem rolar junto, fazendo aquele efeito Parallax simples. 
Porém no Google Chrome, ao rolar a página, a imagem não segue e quebra toda.
No Firefox funciona e, por incrível que pareça, no IE também!
Acontece na página "sobre".

```css
p, h3 {
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 200;
}
ul {
    list-style: outside none none;
}
.social p, a:hover, a:active {
    text-decoration: none;
}
h1, h2, .menu, .ver-mais {
    text-align: center;
}
.ver-mais, .promo-title, .header-bkg, .slide, .separator {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #00011c;
}
.social img, nav li, .box-purple, .ver-mais, .gallery img, .ambiente img, .reside a {
    transition: all 1s ease 0s;
}
.promocoes, .wrapper-sobre, footer, .social p, a:hover, a:active, .menu ul li a {
    color: #fff;
}
.promo-title, .ambiente h1, .portfolio .ver-mais:hover {
    color: #ed297b;
}
.box-purple, .promocoes a, .ver-mais {
    display: block;
}
.ambiente h3 {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.header-bkg, .slide .item, .ambiente img, .separator {
    width: 100%;
}
.box-purple, .promocoes a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.promocoes ul li, .portfolio-item img, .contato {
    padding: 10px;
}
.promocoes ul li, .ambiente p {
    text-align: justify;
}
.ambiente a, .promo-title {
    font-weight: bold;
}
.ver-mais, .ambiente h1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.galeria, .ambiente img, .atendimento, .sala-vip, .localizacao {
    padding: 20px;
}
.menu {
    font-size: 7em;
    margin-right: 5%;
    margin-top: 4%;
}
.header-bkg {
    height: 140px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
}
.slide {
    margin-top: -20%;
    z-index: -5;
}
.slide .item {
    max-height: 500px;
    opacity: 0.6;
}
.promo-bkg-img {
    background: url("../img/tattoo_2.jpg") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.promo-bkg-filter {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 1, 28, 0.38);
}
.box-purple {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #46132d;
}
.box-purple:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #7c2f57;
}
.promo-title {
    font-size: 62pt;
    letter-spacing: 0.7em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.promo-list {
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.portfolio-item img {
    width: 90%;
}
.ver-mais {
    color: #000;
}
.ambiente {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
}
.ambiente a {
    color: #37011d;
}
.ambiente h1 {
    border-top: 1px solid black;
    width: 50%;
}
.ambiente img {
    height: 300px;
}
.ambiente ul li {
    list-style-type: square;
    text-align: left;
}
.gallery img:hover, .ambiente img:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 50px #999;
}
.separator {
    height: 10px;
}
.social {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #010240;
    text-align: center;
}
.social img {
    margin: 20px;
    width: 30%;
}
.social img:hover {
}
.sobre, .atendimento, .sala-vip {
    background: url("../img/texture-bkg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.sobre h1, .atendimento h1, .sala-vip h1, .sobre h2, .atendimento h2, .sala-vip h2, .sobre p, .atendimento p, .sala-vip p {
    color: #000;
}
.sobre img, .atendimento img, .sala-vip img {
    margin: 2% 10%;
    width: 80%;
}
.atendimento p, .sala-vip p {
    color: #fff !important;
}
html {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
body {
    min-height: 100%;
}
html, body {
}
@media not all {
.equips, .sala-vip {
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
}
.equips, .sala-vip {
    padding: 5% 0;
}
.equips h1, .sala-vip h1 {
    text-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
.equips {
    background: url("http://oi61.tinypic.com/2vs1en8.jpg") repeat fixed 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.sala-vip {
    background: url("http://oi61.tinypic.com/dph8n6.jpg") repeat fixed 0 0 / 100% auto rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.contato {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #000149;
    font-size: 15pt;
}
.contato span {
    font-size: 10pt;
}
input:focus, input:hover, textarea:focus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #010240;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in 0s;
}
.footer {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #232323;
    padding: 10px;
}
.reside {
    float: right;
}
.reside a {
    color: #d81900;
}
.reside a:hover {
    color: #fff;
}
.navbar-nav {
    height: 140px;
}
.pagina-ativa, .nav li:hover, .nav li:focus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #ed297b;
    height: 140px;
    margin-top: -47px;
    padding-top: 47px;
}
.nav .active, .nav li a:hover, .nav li a:focus {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
.form-control, .btn-send {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #822c58;
    border: medium none;
    border-radius: 0;
    color: #fff !important;
    font-family: "Playball",cursive;
    font-size: 16pt !important;
    padding: 4px !important;
}
.form-control:-moz-placeholder, .btn-send:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #ecaacc;
}
.form-control::-moz-placeholder, .btn-send::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #ecaacc;
}
.btn-send {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #dc64a1;
    color: #ecaacc !important;
}
.shot {
    display: none;
    opacity: 1;
}
.navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 white;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 380px) {
#logo {
    margin-top: -20px;
    width: 50%;
}
.promo-title {
    font-size: 30pt;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}
.promocoes a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.promocoes ul li {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.ambiente img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 80%;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
.promocoes, .sobre, .galeria {
    background: url("../img/texture-bkg.png") repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 410px) and (max-width: 620px) {
#logo {
    width: 40%;
}
.promo-title {
    font-size: 30pt;
    letter-spacing: 0.3em;
}
.promocoes ul li {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) and (max-width: 800px) {
#logo {
    width: 70%;
}
.navbar-nav {
    margin-top: -33px;
}
.slide {
    height: 420px;
    margin-top: -28%;
}
.promo-title {
    font-size: 40pt;
    letter-spacing: 0.5em;
}
.promocoes a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
}
.promocoes ul li {
    padding-bottom: 1px;
}
.ambiente img {
    height: 400px;
    width: 80%;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 760px) {
.container > .navbar-collapse {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.navbar-collapse {
    padding: 20px 15px !important;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-nav {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.menu {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #333349;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 18pt;
    margin-top: 20% !important;
}
.menu li:hover {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.pagina-ativa {
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1020px) {
.slide .item {
    max-height: 500px;
    width: 100%;
}
.ambiente img {
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
.slide .item {
    max-height: 600px;
}
.ambiente img {
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1920px) {
.slide .item {
    max-height: 1000px;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper-sobre">
    <div class="sobre">
        <div class="container ">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <h1>Sobre</h1>
                    <p>Há 6 anos o Jhony Bigu atua no mercado da tatuagem na Zona Norte e atualmente nas regiões do Itaim Bibi, Vila Nova Conceição e Vila Olímpia.</p>
                    <p>O Jhony Bigu esta altamente qualificados e apresenta um novo conceito de tatuagens personalizadas que segue um alto padrão de qualidade.</p>
                    <p>O tatuador Jhony Bigu é um profissional experiente e qualificado que está apto a ajuda-lo a encontrar ou criar o melhor desenho para sua tatuagem, prestando um atendimento personalizado desde a seleção de ideias até a elaboração da arte final para a tatuagem escolhida.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h2>Studio</h2>
                        <p>O Studio JB Tattoo está constantemente renovando seus equipamentos e materiais em busca da melhor tecnologia e qualidade disponível no mercado. </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="equips fixbg" id="equipamentos">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h1>Equipamentos</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 box-purple">
                        <p>
                            Todos os matérias utilizados no Studio são totalmente descartáveis nas tatuagens, evitando-se o risco
                            de contaminação cruzada. O Studio conta com um ambiente aconchegante para que seus clientes sejam
                            atendidos de forma bastante à vontade, tendo o máximo de conforto durante a elaboração dos desenhos,
                            assim como na realização dos procedimentos de tatuagens.
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="atendimento" id="atendimento">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <h1>Atendimento</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6 box-purple">
                        <p>Política de atendimento:
                            <ul>
                                <li>Cada sessão de tatuagem tem duração de 1 hora</li>
                                <li>Acima de uma sessão de tatuagem ocorrera com duração media de 3 horas (podendo variar de acordo com a resistência e condições de cada cliente).</li>
                                <li>Necessário o preenchimento de Termo de responsabilidade para todos os clientes.</li>
                                <li>Tatuagens para menores de idade somente na presença de um dos responsáveis e mediante o preenchimento do termo de responsabilidade e documentos de identificação com foto.</li>
                            </ul>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="sala-vip fixbg" id="sala-vip">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <h1>Sala Vip</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6 box-purple">
                    <p>
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod
                        tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
                        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo
                        consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse
                        cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
                        proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Como fica ao rolar a página:
[image: imagem quebrada ao rolar a página com background fixed]

Pesquisando na net, achei essa possível solução:

```
 $(document).scroll(function(){
     $(this).find('.fixbg').hide().show(0);
 });
```

Porém com esse código, ao rolar a página, o Scroll não vai até o final, trava nas imagens e não desce mais.

Comment: editei sua pergunta colocando um "code snippet" que seria um executável de código html+css+js com seus códigos lá. porém o exemplo não se torna funcional por causa das imagens que não estão disponíveis, teria como você upar as imagens e atualizar a origem delas no snippet? ou se você não souber, comente aqui o link das imagens e depois que eu adiciona-las pode apagar o comentário.

Comment: Valeu!!! Vou colocar as imagens ali :D

Comment: tens certeza que adicionou todo o html e css necessários? pois não ficou igual a imagem que você demonstrou, deve estar faltando algo, acredito que seja CSS :D

Comment: Vish... Eu uso Less... Vou fazer o seguinte: Vou compilar e colocar ali pra ficar certinho. :D

Comment: Utilizo a Versão 38.0.2125.122 do chrome e funciona normal! testei em outros navegadores e fluiu. Testei seu código sem o javascript - Cara! Testei pelo link que enviou (http://server.gruporeside.com.br/jhonybigutattoo/public/index.php?canal=sobre) e aqui esta normal. O chrome não apresenta nada e anormalidade.

Comment: Opa, verifica por esse link Eduardo: http://server.gruporeside.com.br/jhonybigutattoo/public/index.php?canal=sobre

Comment: Cara! Testei pelo link que enviou (http://server.gruporeside.com.br/jhonybigutattoo/public/index.php?canal=sobre) e aqui esta normal. O chrome não apresenta nada e anormalidade.

Comment: Desculpe, acho que faltou foi minha informação... Acessa a página sobre e tenta rolar até o final... Ele trava antes do formulário do footer.

Comment: Não entendi exatamente onde tá bugando mas aqui pelo menos se você tirar a classe fixbg o scroll vai até o final, mas acho que o efeito que você quer não funciona.

Comment: Oi @haykou! Então, o efeito funciona no Firefox, IE e tudo mais... Só no Chrome que não vai...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Espero que já tenha achado uma outra solução.
No site em inglês, localizei alguém que fez a mesma pergunta.

Invés de "consertar", ele fez um workaround usando a proprieda `clip` e a `position:fixed`.

Veja a pergunta [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23571578/chrome-issue-with-background-attachment-fixed-and-position-fixed-elements) e o [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ywsN7/) que ele fez.
Espero que ajude nas próximas.